# order a list like in xml schema java

Tags: java, xml, list, arraylist

I have an xml like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plane>
<part>
    <desc>qwe</desc>
    <qty>1</qty>
</part>
<part>
    <desc>asd</desc>
    <qty>1</qty>
        <part>
            <desc>asdfg</desc>
            <qty>1</qty>
        </part>
        <part>
            <desc>asdfg</desc>
            <qty>4</qty>
        </part>
    </part>
<part>
    <desc>zxc</desc>
    <qty>2</qty>
</part>
<part>
    <desc>AAAA</desc>
    <qty>1</qty>
        <part>
            <desc>BBBB</desc>
            <qty>1</qty>
                <part>
                    <desc>CCCC</desc>
                    <qty>13</qty>
                        <part>
                            <desc>DDDD</desc>
                            <qty>12</qty>
                                <part>
                                    <desc>EEEE</desc>
                                    <qty>21</qty>
                                </part>
                        </part>
                </part>
                <part>
                    <desc>CCCC1111</desc>
                    <qty>13</qty>
                        <part>
                            <desc>DDDD1111</desc>
                            <qty>12</qty>
                                <part>
                                    <desc>EEEE1111</desc>
                                    <qty>21</qty>
                                </part>
                        </part>
                </part>
        </part>
        <part>
            <desc>G</desc>
            <qty>1</qty>
                <part>
                    <desc>H</desc>
                    <qty>13</qty>
                        <part>
                            <desc>I</desc>
                            <qty>12</qty>
                        </part>
                </part>
        </part>
</part>
</plane>
```

Now I want to print it out in the "same" structure. I created a method, but the output differs from expectes:
Run. class

```
public class Run {

public static void itarate(List<Part> list){
    for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getDesc() + " x " + list.get(i).getQty());
        if (list.get(i).getListParts() != null){
            System.out.print(" -- ");
            itarate(list.get(i).getListParts());

        }
    }
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {



    Converter converter = new XML_Converter();
    Plane plane = converter.readFile();
    //System.out.println(plane);
    List<Part> parts = plane.getPlaneParts();


    itarate(parts);

}

}
```

The output:

```
qwe x 2
AAAA x 1
  BBBB x 1
  CCCC x 13
  DDDD x 12
  EEEE x 21
CCCC1111 x 13
  DDDD1111 x 12
  EEEE1111 x 21
G x 1
  H x 13
  I x 12
```

but I actually want something like:

```
qwe x 2
AAAA x 1
  BBBB x 1
    CCCC x 13
      DDDD x 12
        EEEE x 21
  CCCC1111 x 13
    DDDD1111 x 12
      EEEE1111 x 21
G x 1
  H x 13
    I x 12
```

XML To object Class:

```
public class XML_Converter{

private String filePath = "D:\\file.xml";
private File file = new File(filePath);

@Override
public Plane readFile() {
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Plane.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Plane plane = (Plane) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        return plane;
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to load file. Try again.");
    }
    return new Plane();

}
```

Plane class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Plane {

private List<Part> planeParts = null;


@XmlElement(name="part")
public List<Part> getPlaneParts() {
    return planeParts;
}

public void setPlaneParts(List<Part> planeParts) {
    this.planeParts = planeParts;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Plane [planeParts=" + planeParts + "]";
}


}
```

Parts.class

```
public class Part {

private String desc;
private int qty;

private List<Part> listParts = null;


@XmlElement(name="desc")
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

@XmlElement(name="part")
public List<Part> getListParts() {
    return listParts;
}

@XmlElement(name="qty")
public int getQty() {
    return qty;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public void setListParts(List<Part> listParts) {
    this.listParts = listParts;
}

public void setQty(int qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Part [desc=" + desc + ", qty=" + qty + ", listParts="
            + listParts + "]";
}


}
```

How can I achieve that (so the xml structure is similar to the code output)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include complete code.

Comment: included, as you wished

Comment: I think there is a way to do this without recursion, but it will require changing your XML structure. Also, I think I recognize this "Plane" XML structure from somewhere I worked until recently. If you are doing what I think you are doing, Kudos to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the current recursion level around in a variable (e.g r) and print the number of spaces accordingly

```
public static void itarate(List<Part> list,int r){
    for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0;j<r;j++)
           System.out.print("  ");
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getDesc() + " x " + list.get(i).getQty());
        if (list.get(i).getListParts() != null){
            itarate(list.get(i).getListParts(),r+1);

        }
    }
```

EDIT: Moved the indentation stuff out of the inner loop

Comment: Hmm, setting to 0 makes loop does go only once. Setting to 1 makes a lot of repeated stuff...

Comment: Not currently having a javac at hand. Moved the indentation stuff out of the loop. The basic idea is that you have to modify your indentation based on the recursion depth. Which you didn't do. btw. I would assume that setting r=0 would make the loop iterate never.